# push all the records from DB into one hash in PHP

Tags: php, hash

I am trying to push all the records from DB into one hash (associative array) on the basis of uid (as key) below.

Sample dump of Records from DB:

```
array (size=4)
  'id' => string '18' (length=2)
  'job_title' => string 'Rubyyyy' (length=4)
  'job_skills' => string 'Rubyyyy' (length=4)
  'uid' => string '1' (length=1)

array (size=4)
  'id' => string '19' (length=2)
  'job_title' => string 'Ruby on Rails' (length=13)
  'job_skills' => string 'Ruby on Rails' (length=13)
  'uid' => string '2' (length=1)

array (size=4)
  'id' => string '20' (length=2)
  'job_title' => string 'Ruby' (length=4)
  'job_skills' => string 'Ruby' (length=4)
  'uid' => string '1' (length=1)

array (size=4)
  'id' => string '21' (length=2)
  'job_title' => string 'Rubyon' (length=13)
  'job_skills' => string 'Rubyon' (length=13)
  'uid' => string '2' (length=1)
```

Expected Output:

```
array (size=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '20' (length=2)
      'job_title' => string 'Ruby' (length=4)
      'job_skills' => string 'Ruby' (length=4)
      'uid' => string '1' (length=1)

    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '18' (length=2)
      'job_title' => string 'Rubyyyy' (length=4)
      'job_skills' => string 'Rubyyyy' (length=4)
      'uid' => string '1' (length=1)

  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '21' (length=2)
      'job_title' => string 'Rubyon' (length=13)
      'job_skills' => string 'Rubyon' (length=13)
      'uid' => string '2' (length=1)

    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '19' (length=2)
      'job_title' => string 'Ruby on Rails' (length=13)
      'job_skills' => string 'Ruby on Rails' (length=13)
      'uid' => string '2' (length=1)
```

Comment: hash != associative array

Comment: @Enstage , apologies if it is not same.
Associative arrays in PHP is similar to Hashes in PERL.